# Excel - How to avoid needless repeated queries due to query dependencies?

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I've recently redesigned my Excel workbook with data queries in such a way queries are no longer sourced from the workbook itself, but from outside sources only. This, rather counterintuitively, caused data upload times to increase. Here’s an example of query dependencies I’ve got at the moment:

[image]

I’ve noticed that MB5B and it's external source is queried five times. Once for itself, then four times for each of the other subquery.

How do I avoid repeating the same operation five times?

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense to have Queries within a workbook. But minimising the number of external Queries is generally better for performance (in the same way that pulling data with a minimal number of SQL queries pulling multiple rows is). Then within the workbook use formulae. So can you turn the Data Query here into a single one (or two) that captures all the data, and then get to desired output by formulae?

Comment: I certainly could just pull the main table and then use a combination of SORT, UNIQUE and FILTER to achieve the desired result, but it I wanted to learn some Querring skills and do it the "elegant" way.